# Are "simultaneous connections" in Firebase as restrictive as they appear?

Tags: firebase

I would love to use Firebase as my primary cloud storage service for my HTML5 mobile apps, but I'm having trouble figuring out if the limit on simultaneous connections is going to restrict me from having a lot of non-realtime users as well.

At first glance, it looks like I can only have as many users as the connections I am paying for. What happens when 10,000 people download my app? If my app doesn't need real-time synchronization (polling is sometimes totally fine), is Firebase's architecture still going to limit the amount of concurrent users? Should I just go with couchDB and a VPS?

Thanks!

Comment: 10k connections could mean more or less than 10k users. A user might not leave the connection open all them time (probably) or always make multiple connections.

Comment: So it's possible to simple pull and poll, closing the connection in between? If so, I could see how "1 concurrent corresponds to roughly 1,400 monthly visits." It would be nice to have an example for how connections relate to users for say, a relatively simple twitter client mobile app.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. Keep the connection open. It's probably going to be fine since people don't use *mobile apps for 24 hours a day*! They do sleep, you know.

Comment: The 1:1400 is a pretty good reference for most users; mobile apps actually tend to be lower; we just don't spend that long in phone apps on average

Comment: Kato thanks so much for that. That clears it up for me. If your comment was a top-level reply I would have marked it as having answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

You need many fewer concurrents than your total expected user count. Firebase recommends 1 concurrent for about every 1440 visits, per their [pricing FAQ](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html#faq-1).

So, if you expect to have 10,000 visits, you'll likely see under 10 concurrents most of the time. This keeps you well below the 200 provided by the candle plan.

(Answer copied mostly from comments. Thanks @Kato)

Comment: Hey Jenny, just noticed a slight difference between your (great) answer and the (current) Pricing FAQ. "In our experience, 1 concurrent corresponds to roughly 1,400 monthly **visits**" (emphasis mine).