# limitation and size of google firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to build a big app which can have in future more than 100,000 user ,, can I depend on google firebase ?
more details about app :
app directed to university which have more than million student and we suppose that maximum of students who will join 100,000
and we think that app will start with 10,000 students

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964829/are-simultaneous-connections-in-firebase-as-restrictive-as-they-appear and many from this page https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+concurrent+users

Answer (score 0):

When we are talking about `Firebase`, we are talking about simultaneous connections not about the number of users. If you are looking for a free plan, Firebase provides: `00 simultaneous connections, 1 GB stored and 10 GB/month downloaded. See [Pricing Plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

However, there is no restriction regarding the number of users.

Hope it helps.